# How deploy an ejb independet in WebLogic 12c, which was created in GlassFish 3.1

Tags: web-services, deployment, ejb, weblogic

Good day, I want to deploy an EJB Application Project which contains a class Session Bean and WebServices using JAX-WS library, and the Session Bean uses a remote interface that is in another JavaApplication Project. I use the Session Bean from WebServices using injection and everything works fine.
I wish I could use both web services as the session bean from another project located in another application server. At first I used for development GlassFish 3 with NetBeans IDE, but it was difficult for me to deploy the EJB in another machine with GlassFish installed and now I'm dealing with WebLogic server 12c. I installed WebLogic and used Administration Console to deploy the JavaApplication that contained the remote interface, then I deployed the EJB selecting in the left panel "Deployment" and then "Install" and browsed for the .jar that is located in the folder dist of the EJB project. But then i get the following error:

[EJB:015001]Unable to link class service.Services in Jar C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\domain\servers\AdminServer\stage\BancaSimulacionIBancaria\BancaSimulacionIBancaria.jar : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: service/ServicesRemote

I want to know what do before deploying the EJB, what needs to be done?

[image]

Comment: Well... is the remote interface packaged in the ejb module that you try to deploy?

Comment: No.. I have a .jar(EJB) that is generated by the IDE Netbeans, but i don't know how put in the .jar which contain the remote interface in the package .jar of the EJB?.. I was deploying the library which the remote interface, before the deploy of EJB in the WebLogic server but doesn't work.